# Easy way to create invoices with PHP and TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, xls, tcpdf, invoice

I'm currently working on a project with an invoice function, in PHP. In the administration panel employees can see all the details of the customers and there, it is also possible to click and create invoices, reminders etc. in PDF format. For that I am using TCPDF and [their examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php). It works great but the problem that I'm having now is that it's a real struggle to convert the invoices from the old format (`.xls`) to TCPDF. I am currently having to align every single line of text very precisely.

Is there an easier way to get it done?

Comment: What's the question? Where's the code?

Comment: It sounds like you will need to write a script for this. First you will need to convert the .xls to csv. Then you can parse these comma separated values and generate corresponding PDFs just as you did for the new invoices.

Comment: PHPExcel can use PDF libraries, if you're already used to it, it might be the way to go. 'phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/432897' also here is a php code example: 'weberdev.com/get_example.php3?ExampleID=4023'